# How to setup ZendeskApi client for rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configuration

What is the most optimal way to set up ZendeskApi client for rails app?

```
require 'zendesk_api'

class Zendesk
  class << self
    def client
      @client ||= ZendeskAPI::Client.new do |config|
        config.url = 'https://rockcodehelp.zendesk.com/api/v2'
        config.username = "dariusz.finster@gmail.com/token"
        config.token = "xxx"

        require 'logger'
        config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But maybe should I move it to initialiser somehow?

This is a gem: https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_api_client_rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class looks fine. No need to move it to an initializer because the Client class has an initialize (new) method, but no builder. So, I would keep things simple and just initialize the class as you did.

Comment: I am wondering why I am receiving now messages like this: `You are setting a key that conflicts with a built-in method Hashie::Mash#class defined in Kernel. This can cause unexpected behavior when accessing the key via as a property. You can still access the key via the #[] method.`

Comment: What is the result of Zendesk.client?

Comment: The authentication and connection seem to happen fine... I would check the issues on the github repository of the gem and ask there for more info. Seems to be a Hashie problem.